# How to render minified js file under dist folder on gh-pages

Tags: vue.js, github-pages, nuxt.js

I just followed [this](https://github.com/koop4/koop4.github.io) video to generate a app using vueJs cli, and I'd like to deploy the result on the `gh-pages`.

I generated the dist folder running the `yarn generate` command, and 
 followed [this guide](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) to deploy that folder.

However, as you can see  [here](https://koop4.github.io/), it render the `README.md` file.

[Here](https://github.com/koop4/koop4.github.io) is the repository. What would you change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake thinking the gh-pages branch was rendered. It was the master branch since user and organization must use the master branch for that.

I solved by creating a new branch to use for development, and the master to render the website.

Everything works now.

Comment: Good feedback. +1. I have deleted my answer.